# How do I get form to submit a php/mysql function and then refresh

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a form inside php...Basically it is a cart with books.I want to implement the remove button such that when a buyer clicks the remove button, the item is subtracted from the cart database...right now I have a form and I have set the method and the action accordingly but I don't know how to get it to perform the function onclick and then refresh the page which should now show the cart with the updated value...
Here is my form code

```
echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
    echo "<td><input  name='$isbn' type='submit' value='Remove'></td>";
    echo "</form>";
```

and here is my php function to update the cart

```
          function remove($db, $format, $isbn) {
if ($format = 'hardcover') {


    $query = 'UPDATE cart SET hardcover_purchased=hardcover_purchased-1 WHERE isbn=0061348112';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':isbn', $isbn);

    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $result;
} elseif ($format = 'softcover') {
    $query = 'UPDATE cart SET softcover_purchased=softcover_purchased-1 WHERE isbn=0061348112';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':isbn', $isbn);

    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $result;
} else {
    $query = 'UPDATE cart SET ebook_purchased=ebook_purchased-1 WHERE isbn=0061348112';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':isbn', $isbn);

    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $result;
}
}
```

Comment: You'll have to check the `$_POST` array for whatever `$isbn` resolves to be in the button's name.  Then based on the value of that, perform your logic accordingly.

Comment: That is going to generate invalid HTML. You can't have a form as a parent element of a td.

Comment: ...meaning, `<form>` cannot be child of `<table>`.

Comment: The implementation principles do no really differ from what you have used for adding an item to the cart...

Comment: @David thanks, I used the same procedure as I use to insert book and it worked